# Poker hand history as an XML file, what language to use and how to begin manipulation

Tags: xml, poker

Hello Stack Overflow users,
I am a semi-professional online poker player who isn't good enough to leave his day job.  I am teaching myself to write code using treehouse and devslopes for the purpose of being able to write my own poker tracking data.  I currently use Poker Copilot 6 and I like the simplicity but I only use about 10 percent of the features and need a few features added.

This brings me to my question, I need to know what language I should be concentrating on(so far mainly javascript) to show and manipulate data.  I will include a sample hand history so you can see how it looks.  Once I pick a language, where can I find examples of people using the language to work with an XML file so I can reach a greater understanding of what I am reaching for?

```
<game id="87931844-11" starttime="20170722181243" numholecards="2" gametype="23" stakes="No Limit Level 5 Ante 10, Blinds 50/100" seats="9" realmoney="true" data="20170722|8 x $11 Coupon GTD Satellite [Turbo] (87927310-1)|87927310-1|87931844-11|true" buyIn="1.00" seatsPerTable="9" tableCount="4" startingStack="3000.00" rebuy="1.00" rebuyStack="3000.00" addon="1.00" addonStack="3000.00" bounty="0.00" version="2.1" >
    <players dealer="5" >
        <player seat="0" nickname="Tig1997" balance="2610.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="1" nickname="13TSWIFT13" balance="4965.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="2" nickname="BB4One" balance="2500.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="3" nickname="pokerlou1117" balance="3290.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="4" nickname="p7469j" balance="3000.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="5" nickname="StakAttak" balance="4330.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="7" nickname="VanCouverJr" balance="10505.00" dealtin="true" />
        <player seat="8" nickname="boatbuilderm" balance="2500.00" dealtin="true" />
    </players>
    <round id="BLINDS" sequence="1" >
        <event sequence="1" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="0" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="2" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="1" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="3" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="2" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="4" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="3" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="5" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="4" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="6" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="5" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="7" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="7" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="8" type="ANTE" timestamp="1500765163000" player="8" amount="10.00" />
        <event sequence="9" type="SMALL_BLIND" timestamp="1500765163000" player="7" amount="50.00" />
        <event sequence="10" type="BIG_BLIND" timestamp="1500765163000" player="8" amount="100.00" />
    </round>
    <round id="PREFLOP" sequence="2" >
        <event sequence="11" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765164000" player="0" />
        <event sequence="12" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765176000" player="1" />
        <event sequence="13" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765179000" player="2" />
        <event sequence="14" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765181000" player="3" />
        <event sequence="15" type="ALL_IN" timestamp="1500765184000" player="4" amount="2990.00" />
        <event sequence="16" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765184000" player="5" />
        <event sequence="17" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765188000" player="7" />
        <event sequence="18" type="FOLD" timestamp="1500765189000" player="8" />
        <cards type="HOLE" cards="7s,9s" player="8" hand="Nine High" />
    </round>
    <round id="END_OF_FOLDED_GAME" sequence="3" >
        <event sequence="19" type="MUCK" timestamp="1500765190000" player="4" />
        <winner amount="330.00" uncalled="false" potnumber="1" player="4" pottype="n" />
        <winner amount="2890.00" uncalled="true" potnumber="2" player="4" pottype="n" />
    </round>
    <round id="END_OF_GAME" sequence="4" >
    </round>
</game>
```

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to use this opportunity to switch to IT job and earn good money? Do you want to learn programming so you can solve similar math/etc problems in future for yourself? Are you interested just in this single problem and focus is on poker itself, rather than programming? Or is it a journey to expand your mind and skillset, same way as some people want to play an instrument or paint, without ever becoming an paid or performing artist? Please do not answer 'all of above to some extent', because it is never like that :) Depending on your final goal, advice will differ.

Comment: Artur, I have just switched to an IT job and am tasked with using infusionsoft and process maker mainly.  For now any programming I am learning is simply for my own edification and all that I learn I would like to be centered around creating the software for my poker tracker.